# Ajax's JSON return undefined objects

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, fancybox

i'm trying to create a fancybox gallery with Ajax's Json method. 
Script is divided in three parts

**Ajax Call :**

```
function getimage(id) {

    $.ajax({    
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'getimages.php',
        data:'user='+id,
        success: function(data){

            $.fancybox([data], {
                    'padding': 0,
                    'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    'type'  : 'image',
                    'changeFade' : 0,
                    'topRatio'    : 0.2
             });
        }
    });
    return false
}
```

**Page getimages.php :**

```
<?  

include 'config.php'; connect(); session_start();

$user_id = trim(strip_tags($_GET['user']));

$query = "SELECT url as href FROM post WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND type = 'photo'";
$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query($query);

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

$json_response = json_encode($arr);

echo $json_response;
```

?>

**Json Response:**

```
[{"href":"1df4fddf370b2e89949bbf5d6e11e037_1381707753.jpg"},{"href":"42a4701b45eb5b17cee7a8fe1beb4c48_1381957761.jpg"}]
```

Long story short, each photos have as "onclick" getimage(id) where "id" is the user id.
So getimage.php should searching for all photos'user and with json method view these as gallery.

The problem is that data return undefined object (tested it with lovely "alert(data)" obj,[obj]) .
Now, What could be the problem ?... and i'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: **Object** can be shown in **Console** not in **alert()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is already an **array** use it like,

```
....
success: function(data){
     console.log(data);// check in console
     if(data.length)
     {  
        $.fancybox(data, { // use data in place of [data]
           'padding': 0,
           'transitionIn': 'none',
           'transitionOut': 'none',
           'type'  : 'image',
           'changeFade' : 0,
           'topRatio'    : 0.2
        });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug use `console.log(var mixed);`
if the data is an JSON-Object/String use `var myObj = eval('(' + data + ')');` to get an JS-Object.